# When is it possible to split three sets?

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

There are three sets, each of which contains some $2 k$ elements. The sets may overlap.

Is it possible to color the elements red and green, such that each set contains exactly $k$ red and $k$ green elements?

If $k$ is odd, then this may be impossible. For example, suppose the sets are:
$$
S_1 = \{1,2,~~ 4,5,~~ 7,8,~~ \ldots, 3k-2, 3k-1 \}
\\
S_2 = \{2,3,~~ 5,6,~~ 8,9,~~ \ldots, 3k-1, 3k \}
\\
S_3 = \{3,1,~~ 6,4,~~ 9,7,~~ \ldots, 3k, 3k-2 \}
$$
Each set contains exactly $2k$ elements.
Each element appears in exactly two sets, so if there were exactly $k$ red elements in each set, the number of red elements overall should have been $3 k /2$ by double-counting. But this is impossible since $k$ is odd.

The remaining case is that $k$ is even. Is it always possible to split the sets in this case?

Comment: I would write a system like this: $$\begin{cases}
x_{1}+x_{12}+x_{13}+x_{123}=2k \\
x_{2}+x_{12}+x_{23}+x_{123}=2k \\ 
x_{3}+x_{13}+x_{23}+x_{123}=2k \\   
\end{cases}
$$ where e.g. $x_{12}$ are the elements belonging to $S_1$ and $S_2$ only, and so on. Then divide each variable in equal parts for the red and green elements. For odd values, we are left with $1$ element unpaired. We rewrite the system $\pmod 2$, then we have  only $5$ or $6$ isomorphic classes of solutions (surely less than $10$). We can then color the elements appropriately for each of these specific solutions.

Comment: And probably the only case that we cannot color is the one that you found: $x_1=x_2=x_3=x_{123}=0, x_{12}=x_{13}=x_{23}=1$.